# JavaScript JTable - Null value with multiple cascaded lists/dropdowns

Tags: javascript, c#, jtable

I am using the latest version of JTable from http://jtable.org/ (downloaded it yesterday). I setup my JTable as shown below (I also included the server-side code below, which is written in C#). The List function works (the data shows up in the table), the Add function works, and the Delete function works. However, when I go to Edit a row, there is an error when trying to populate the data for the "ElevationsMulti" field. I get an error that simply says, "Cannot load options for field ElevationsMulti."

**JTable Code:**

```
    $('#ReportsContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Reports',
        actions: {
            listAction: '/Report_SingleEstimate/GetReportNames?customerId=' + customerId,
            createAction: '/Report_SingleEstimate/AddReport',
            updateAction: '/Report_SingleEstimate/EditReport',
            deleteAction: '/Report_SingleEstimate/DeleteReport'
        },
        fields: {
            ReportID: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            ReportName: {
                title: 'Report Name'
            },
            CustomerID: {
                title: 'Customer',
                list: false,
                options: '/Estimates/GetCustomers',
                defaultValue: customerId
            },
            PlanNameID: {
                title: 'Plan Name',
                dependsOn: 'CustomerID',
                options: function (data) {
                    if (data.source == 'list') {
                        return '/Estimates/GetListOfPlanNames?customerId=0';
                    }

                    //data.source == 'edit' || data.source == 'create'
                    return '/Estimates/GetListOfPlanNames?customerId=' + data.dependedValues.CustomerID;
                }
            },
            ProductID: {
                title: 'Product',
                options: '/Estimates/GetProducts'
            },
            HeaderFieldsMulti: {
                title: 'Fields',
                options: '/Report_SingleEstimate/GetHeaderFields',
                type: 'multiselectddl',
                list: false
            },
            ElevationsMulti: {
                title: 'Elevations',
                type: 'multiselectddl',
                dependsOn: ['PlanNameID', 'ProductID'],
                options: function (data) {
                    if (data.source == 'list') {
                        return '/Elevation/GetAllElevations';
                    }

                    return '/Report_SingleEstimate/GetElevations?PlanNameID=' + data.dependedValues.PlanNameID +
                           '&ProductID=' + data.dependedValues.ProductID;
                },
                list: false
            }
        }
    });

    $('#ReportsContainer').jtable('load');
```

Not sure if it makes a difference in JTable, but the ElevationsMulti depends on the PlanNameID and ProductID fields, and the PlanNameID field depends on the CustomerID fields. In other words, the ElevationsMulti field depends on a field that depends on another field (multiple nested dropdowns).

**C# server-side code:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetElevations(int PlanNameID, int ProductID)
    {
        try
        {
            int estimateId = Estimates.getEstimateId(PlanNameID, ProductID);
            List<MyDropdownList> elevations = Estimate_ElevationList.listElevationsByEstimateForDropdown(estimateId);

            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Options = elevations });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

**Error here:**

Further debugging has given me a more specific error.

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'PlanNameID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetElevations(Int32, Int32)' in 's84.Controllers.Report_SingleEstimateController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.*

Basically, JTable sends PlanNameID to the server as a null value. Which seems to indicate that JTable has not loaded the options for the PlanNameID field yet when it makes the server call for the ElevationsMulti field.

How do I make JTable wait to load the ElevationsMulti field until after the PlanNameID field has been loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem came from using the Type "multiselectddl" in JTable. I changed the code in JTable that creates the multiselectddl to the same code as the regular dropdown. Here is the code:

```
    _createInputForRecordField: function (funcParams) {
        ...

        //Create input according to field type
        if (field.type == 'date') {
            return this._createDateInputForField(field, fieldName, value);
        } else if (field.type == 'textarea') {
            return this._createTextAreaForField(field, fieldName, value);
        } else if (field.type == 'password') {
            return this._createPasswordInputForField(field, fieldName, value);
        } else if (field.type == 'checkbox') {
            return this._createCheckboxForField(field, fieldName, value);
        } else if (field.options) {
            if (field.type == 'multiselectddl') {
                return this._createDropDownListMultiForField(field, fieldName, value, record, formType, form);
            } else if (field.type == 'radiobutton') {
                return this._createRadioButtonListForField(field, fieldName, value, record, formType);
            } else {
                return this._createDropDownListForField(field, fieldName, value, record, formType, form);
            }
        } else {
            return this._createTextInputForField(field, fieldName, value);
        }
    },

    _createDropDownListMultiForField: function (field, fieldName, value, record, source, form) {
        //Create a container div
        var $containerDiv = $('<div class="jtable-input jtable-multi-dropdown-input"></div>');

        //Create multi-select element
        var $select = $('<select multiple="multiple" class="' + field.inputClass + '" id="Edit-' + fieldName + '" name=' + fieldName + '></select>')
            .appendTo($containerDiv);

        var options = this._getOptionsForField(fieldName, {
            record: record,
            source: source,
            form: form,
            dependedValues: this._createDependedValuesUsingForm(form, field.dependsOn)
        });

        this._fillDropDownListWithOptions($select, options, value);

        return $containerDiv;
    }
```